# How to install opus codec for playback on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, codec

How do I install the opus audio codec onto my Windows 10 machine? I have an mkv file with HEVC video and OPUS audio.

- When I play the file in VLC, its fine
- Windows 10 Film and TV app: there is video but no sound
- Media Player Classic: there is no sound or audio.

The official site (http://opus-codec.org/downloads/) has the actual dlls, but nothing to 'install' them to windows. I also tried installing the Web Media Extensions from the Windows store, but that does nothing. I'm running Windows 10 Pro 1709 16299.371

- What do I need to install to get sound for the Windows 10 films and tv app
- What do I need to install to get sound and video for media player classic?

Comment: For the record, it _looks_ like (though I could be misinterpreting, if `Opus` got supported but not `MatroskaOpus`,) ["Media Player Classic" has supported the Opus codec since 2012](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/2512#comment%3A11). If it's not playing *there*, that's a bug / technical problem in MPC-HC.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install, in the package are exe files that you use in the command line.

> Opus-tools provides command-line utilities to encode, inspect, and decode .opus files. Opusfile provides application developers with a high-level API for decoding and seeking in .opus files. DLLs for the required libraries libogg 1.3.2, libopus 1.1.1 and openssl, are also included in the binary package.

Answer (score 1):

Install Web Media Extensions from Microsoft Store. Web link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/web-media-extensions/9n5tdp8vcmhs

Videos containing opus audio will play well but for audio files, extension .opus isn't recognized therefore .mp3 would suffice.

Note: *Web Media Extensions* supports UWP only so apps like *Groove Music* and *Movies and TV* will work.

Comment: `for audio files, extension .opus isn't recognized therefore .mp3 would suffice` - this is **false as of (at least) Win10-1903**. Renaming a file from `.opus` to `.mp3` did _not_ enable Windows Media Player to play it (even with WME installed), whereas Groove Music (the other included media player) was able to play my OGG/Opus file _regardless_ of its extension.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude It's because Windows Media player uses internal decoders. WME (now comes pre-installed) supports UWP only.

Comment: Microsoft, always 10 years later on open formats...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a really late answer but I'll add it in case it helps someone.

For playback on Media Player Classic, installing a codec pack like K-Lite Codec Pack Mega should do the job. I recommended K-Lite because the pack distributes Media Player Classic (the maintained 'Black Edition' fork after the official MPC:HC was discontinued) along with other codecs so it should be compatible. I always directly install K-Lite Mega Codec Pack instead of standalone MPC.

I couldn't find a solution to the lack of sound playback on Films & TV, but personally I was asked to install [HEVC Video Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions/9nmzlz57r3t7) (paid) to play HEVC videos in it. Maybe you had [HEVC Video Extensions for Device Manufacturers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9n4wgh0z6vhq) (same, but free and unlisted) pre-installed. Considering Microsoft makes normal users pay for such a basic feature, I don't think that their player should be relied upon as a full-fledged video player.

Edit:

Today I came across [this page](https://codecguide.com/windows_media_codecs.htm) from codecguide.com which said that the free version (for device manufacturers) requires a GPU capable of decoding HEVC and otherwise they have to use the 1$ variant.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome.  Works on v85 and I suspect earlier versions.

I often fall back to chrome on win 10 for open standards media files and have been doing so for a few years e.g. downloads from BBC iplayer.

(Don't know if it is necessary with chrome but already had WME from MS store installed)

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the opusdec.exe to C:\Windows & launch the media file using Windows Media Player. Plays the audio part flawlessly.

Comment: Actually don't work